# Jquery ajax get request not working inside on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, asynchronous

I am writing a web page which shows restaurants in a specified city.
Back end is a node server which uses yelp API for getting results and forwards it as JSON.

In the javascript file, when I call the ajax get method inside `document.ready()` function, it works fine. Console shows `XHR finished loading` .

But when I run it inside jquery click function like this, it doesn't work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#btn').click(function(){

        var city = $('#city').val();      
        var post = $.ajax({
          url: "/query?city=" + city,
          type: "GET"
        });

       post.done(function(json){
           window.alert('ok');
       });

       post.fail(function(json){    
           window.alert('failed'); 

       });
     });    
   });
```

It alerts 'failed' and console says `XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost/query?city=colombo".`

But in the node server it takes the request and processes. When I directly paste `http://localhost/query?city=colombo` into address bar of the browser or to Postman, it gets the request.

Can you please explain me why it only fails inside jquery click function, but works fine outside it...

Comment: when I pause the javascript execution for a few seconds and the continue it, giving time for the JSON to be sent by the node server, it alerts 'ok'..

Comment: Try to put the ajax call inside a timeout and see if fails again

Comment: Html is here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rmksstr1/)

Comment: It fails even outside of onClick function when wrapped inside a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML button you're missing the **type** attribute

```
<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-block col-8">Search</button>
```

The problem is that, since your button is in a form the click will trigger the submit, and the page will reload.

Another way of preventing that is changing your event listener to this:

```
 $('#btn').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ...
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed it!

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, since you have a form

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {

    var city = $('#city').val();      
    var post = $.ajax({
      url: "/query?city=" + city,
      type: "GET"
    });

   post.done(function(json){
       window.alert('ok');
   });

   post.fail(function(json){    
       window.alert('failed'); 

   });
});
```

Comment: You can't bind a "submit" event to a button, it'll never fire! You should select the form instead!

Comment: @FrankCadilac haha, good catch, that what I was saying but I just copied his code and forgot to change from `btn` to `form` :D

Comment: Anyway you should also add a `e.preventDefault()` otherwise the page will reload and the Ajax won't work